# Merge all pages of a pdf to one text with PDFMiner for Python

Tags: python, pdfminer

I'm trying to merge all pages of a PDF-File to one single text and save this text to a JSON-file.

I get no issue but it extracts the text only from the first page of the PDF-File.

How can I iterate through the PDF-File and append the text to JSON-File? Thank you for your hints.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io
from io import StringIO
from io import BytesIO
import os
import glob
import json

pdf_path = 'pdfs' 
pdfFiles = [os.path.join(pdf_path, f) for f in os.listdir(pdf_path) if f.endswith(".pdf") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pdf_path, f))]

extractTextFromPdf(pdfFiles[0])

def extractTextFromPdfByPage(pdf_path):
 with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
    resourceManager = PDFResourceManager()
    returnString = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laParams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(resourceManager, returnString, codec=codec, laparams=laParams)

    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
        fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
        converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
        page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
        yield text

        converter.close()
        fake_file_handle.close()

        data = {'id': filename, 'text': text}

        json_path = 'stage0.json'

        with open(json_path, 'w') as fh:
            json.dump(data, fh)

        return text

    device.close()
    returnString.close()

def extractTextFromPdf(pdf_path):
    for page in extractTextFromPdfByPage(pdf_path):
        print(page)
        print()
```

Comment: *"only from the first page"*: You do `return text`, therefore the loop ends.

Comment: Thx you save my day. My fault...